# How different classifiers would perform on a particular data set

Tags: decision-trees, naive-bayes-classifier, k-nn

I am reading through and learning how different ML methods work on different types of data, but I have faced a data set that I am not sure how ML methods, such as **decision tree, Naive Bayes, and KNN**, would perform on the following data sets (I'm sorry I couldn't find a clearer image). X1 ~ X6 are distinguishing attributes, while X7 ~ X14 are noise attributes. I would really appreciate how each ML method would go about fitting these data sets to the model and what their respective strengths and weaknesses are to these particular data sets.

**Data A:**
[image: p1]

**Data B:**

[image: p2]

Comment: From the graph we can clearly see that a linear model would not work well. Therefore non linear models like Decision Tree, Random Forest, SVM will perform better.

Comment: @spectre Are you talking about Data B only?

Answer (score 1):

From the graph It is very clear that a **non-linear model** will perform well to distinguish between Class A and Class B . A Linear model ( Logistic Regression) give an **accuracy around 50% for such datasets** . A non-linear model (For example -SVM ) with a **kernel trick** can give you a very good accuracy . Follow [this link](https://github.com/par1hsharma/Machine-Learning/blob/master/SVM/SVM%20for%20Non%20Linearly%20Seperable%20Data.ipynb) to see the practical difference between Logistic Regression and SVM for Non-linear Dataset

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, I am particularly interested in how decision tree, Naive Bayes, and KNN will perform on those datasets.

Comment: Decision tree will perform good however  Naive bayes is a weak classifier due to many assumptions it holds as a result it will not perform well on such data set and same goes for KNN . A dataset forming above graph , KNN will not be able to perform well too.

Comment: As stated above a decision tree might perform well as it can model in non linear relationships as well. Naive Bayes is usually used when we have a NLP task at hand as it can perform well on large dataset. KNN might or might not perform well.